# Showing background transparent image in android

Tags: android, libgdx, textures, image, transparency

I have a image with transparent background created from photoshop.

[image]

I added this to my android game which I am creating using libgdx. But when I add it to that, it is shown with white background like following.

[image]

Whats the reason for this? How can I fix this?

Comment: Your other images appear to display correctly. Are they at the same format ?

Comment: No, I painted its background with same colour

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the code where you initialize your texture and where you draw it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cdwijayarathna/cf4c6fe83182e1db37dbe0297f85eaf3

Comment: What image format did you save your sprite in?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to stick a

```
batch.enableBlending()
```

for the sprite inside of the `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`. The reason this works is because what blending does is merge the translucent pixels with the previously drawn ones.

Because blending can incur a performance cost from all the merging magic as opposed to whopping on a straight texture, it's beneficial to simply disable blending unless you're using it yourself.

e.g

```
batch.begin();
batch.disableBlending();
// draw all the other stuff FIRST to save on performance
batch.enableBlending();
myCoolSprite.draw(Batch);
batch.end();
```

For more information about this area you can check out [This handy old wiki page.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites)

Comment: I still see the same outcome.

Comment: Try `batch.enableBlending()` on its own outside the `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`.

Comment: still it doesn't work

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to add some code to the question then.